# What is satellite information in data structures?

Tags: algorithm, pointers, data-structures, b-tree

Taken from **Introduction to Algorithms** by Thomas Cormen:

> To keep things simple, we assume, as we have for binary search trees and red-black
> trees, that any “satellite information” associated with a key is stored in the same
> node as the key. In practice, one might actually store with each key just a pointer to
> another disk page containing the satellite information for that key. The pseudocode
> in this chapter implicitly assumes that the satellite information associated with a
> key, or the pointer to such satellite information, travels with the key whenever the
> key is moved from node to node.

So I've been trying to Google the meaning of the term satellite information but I can't find any (covered by things about NASA). My understanding based on the text alone is that "satellite information" is an address to the location of the actual key value like a pointer? Am I correct or did I misunderstand it?

EDIT: What makes it different from a key?

Comment: The answer to your very last question is most certainly "Yes".

Comment: @KerrekSB "did I misunderstand it?" that one..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Satellite data refers to any "payload" data which you want to store in your data structure and which is *not* part of the *structure* of the data structure. It can be anything you want. It can be a single value, a large collection of values, or a pointer to some other location that holds the value.

For example, here's a list node for a singly linked list whose satellite data is a single integer:

```c
struct node
{
    node * next;
    int satellite;
};
```

In other words, the whole value of any given data structure lies in the data which it contains, which is the satellite data in your book's terminology. The data structure will additionally consume structural data (like the `next` pointer in the example) to perform the algorithms which define it, but those are essentially "overhead" from the user's perspective.

For associative containers, the "key" value performs a dual role: On the one hand it is user data, but on the other hand it is also part of the structure of the container. However, a tree can be equipped with additional satellite data, in which case it becomes a "map" from key data to satellite data.

At one extreme you have a fixed-size array which has *no* overhead and only payload data, and on the other extreme you have complicated structures like multiindexes, tries, Judy arrays, or lockfree containers which maintain a comparably large amount of structural data.

Comment: But what makes it different from a "key"?

Comment: @vincentbelkin: The key is needed for the operation of the tree. Everything else isn't. Let me edit that.

Comment: @vincentbelkin: The situation is even more confusing in a trie: The "values" of a trie are actually made up of lots of "key"s... but the point is that satellite data is *never* involved in the structural algorithms.

Comment: ohh! like BST trees use their key values to determine where to insert the new node right?

Comment: @vincentbelkin: Yes, right. The point of an *associative* data structure is that it incorporates the key into the structural arrangement of the data.

Comment: But why do we call them so? What's the logic association between real-life satellites and the data?

Comment: The word **satellite** has several definitions. My guess is that, in this case, **satellite** is referring to the following definition: *something that is separated from or on the periphery of something else but is nevertheless dependent on or controlled by it.*