# When do you call stable_sort() on scalars?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, primitive, stable-sort

Is it ever good to call `stable_sort` instead of `sort` on scalar types (i.e. `int`, `long`, etc.) with the default comparator?

If so, when should you do this?

If not, then why don't standard libraries just forward such calls to `sort`? Wouldn't that be much faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stable sorts are really only useful when the items you are sorting have [satellite information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551845/what-is-satellite-information-in-data-structures).

---

From CLRS (*Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Ed.*):

> "In practice, the numbers to be sorted are rarely isolated values. Each is usually part
>   of a collection of data called a record. Each record contains a key, which is the
>   value to be sorted. The remainder of the record consists of satellite data, which are
>   usually carried around with the key. In practice, when a sorting algorithm permutes
>   the keys, it must permute the satellite data as well."

---

When a sort is stable, it means that **ties are broken in the sorted array by the items' original ordering**. If you are only sorting `int` and `long` types, you don't need a stable sort.

Comment: So basically STL implementations overlooked the opportunity of redirecting `stable_sort` to `sort` for scalars? (+1 for "satellite information", hadn't heard that term before.)

Comment: @Mehrdad I think they trust users of the language to know when to use which algorithm.

Comment: But how are you supposed to know the data type ahead of time, e.g. inside a template?

Comment: @Mehrdad A stable sort is only used when an object has more data than is used to perform comparisons. So chances are if you need a stable sort, you would've written a custom comparison function. The fact that customization is needed for every type defeats the purpose of a template. So, if you're creating a template (which is inherently compatible with many types), you'll likely be using `std::sort`.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no difference (maybe with exception of things like -0.0 and 0.0). However I do not think there is any need to forward such calls, because std::sort or std::stable_sort should not know what they are sorting, so long as the comparison operation compiles. These functions don't need to be too smart.

Answer (score 3):

With the *default* comparator specifically (implying the natural strict ordering)? I don't see any use for stable sorting on scalars in that case. Stable sorting can't provide any additional benefits in situations when equivalent values (according to the comparator) are indistinguishable. (Although @Andrey Tuganov in his answer makes an interesting and relevant remark about negative zeros).

Nevertheless stable sorting on scalars might be useful when the ordering criterion is weaker than the natural strict ordering. For example, you can write a comparison predicate that will say that any odd number is greater than any even number. In that case the resultant ordering will simply partition the array into contiguous blocks of even and odd numbers (in that order). If you are interested in keeping the relative order of these numbers unchanged, you need stable sorting algorithm.

Comment: +1, absolutely. Note that `stable_partition` should also be considered in a case with only two categories.